# Запись процессов в файл пользователей имена которых начинаются на определенные символы

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, администрирование

Стоит задача, необходимо найти процессы пользователей и записать их в файл, процессы всех пользователей имена которых начинаются на определенные символы, допустим `us`
 Я ввожу команду `ps aux | grep "^[us].*" > info_proc.txt`
Но в файл записываются все процессы от моего имени, а не от имен которые начинаются на `us` в чем ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Уберите квадратные скобки ps aux | grep "^us" > info_proc.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^[us]` означает: любая строка, которая начинается либо на `u` либо на `s`.

Замените на [`rg '^us'`](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/), чтобы найти строки, начинающиеся на `us`.

Чтобы получить информацию о процессах в JSON формате, можно Питон использовать:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import pustil  # apt install python-psutil || pip install psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.username().startswith('us'):
        print(json.dumps(process.as_dict()))
```

Answer (score 1):

День добрый.

Вам подойдет **pgrep**

```
~$ pgrep REGEX
~$ pgrep -u user1,user2
```

выдаст все  PID найденного патерна пользователя.

---

UPD

**pgrep** использует регулярки только к имени программы и параметрам командной строки. Параметр -u принимает полное имя пользователя или несколько через запятую.

Ссылки

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep
- https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/spices/cix-procps-ng.org

Comment: не работает: `pgrep -u 'r.+'` говорит неверное имя пользователя (`pgrep -u root` без ошибок).  [man pgrep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) не упоминает, что regex вообще должны поддерживаться для `-u`

Comment: @jfs Operands

pattern
    Specifies an Extended Regular Expression for matching against the process names or command lines. странно что не работает

Comment: эта цитата не имеет отношения к `-u` опции (options). Она описывает позиционный параметр (operands). Где вы эту команду пробовали?

Comment: @jfs да мой косяк, pgrep использует регулярки для для программы и параметров командной строки, пользователи должны быть указаны буквально через запятую если больше одного. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Ну имена можно получить через getent.